# Is syslog over udp safe on a local network?

Tags: networking, syslog

I have a device that doesn't support sending tls syslog traffic, and can only send udp syslog. I'm only sending logs over my local network, but I'm worried the non-tls data can be read by anyone on the network. The device and syslog server are on the `0.0.1.0/24` subnet, and devices I'm worried about are both on `0.0.1.0/24` and `0.0.2.0/24`.

Maybe i understand promiscuous mode wrong, but it sounds like anyone can just listen in to those packets.

Answer (score 1):

In theory anything on the same subnet can not only see the packets but also inject log messages. Therefore you don't need to worry about 0.0.2.0/24 unless your router is applying some funky rules to UDP packets.

In practice, across wifi and switched ethernet, other hosts on the same subnet are not likely to see the packets as they (mostly) won't appear on the cable / wifi connection they are using.

Comment: Is there a way for me to test this myself? Maybe with wireshark?

Comment: yes, or tcpdump if you don't have Linux/MS-Windows with GUI accessible on the network.

Comment: So I'll start wireshark on 0.0.1.0/24 and i should start seeing packets from the device to the syslog server? I'm sorry if i don't understand it very well.

Comment: ....if you're using the same physical connection as the client or server.